# Python Selenium Headless Download and Window-Sizing Problems

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

Now Chrome is updated to 110.0.5481.104 I got some Problems with my existing Python Code which I cannot figure out alone. Since last Week I noticed some Problems with the Download Function, so I saw that the new Version needs to run with

```
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

instead of

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Nice, that fixed the “Download Bug”. But since then, I noticed, that some Downloads could not even be created. So I checked out with some Screenshot what happend, and it seems now, that the

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

is not applied so some Elements on the Website are not Clickable.

This only happens, when the Task Scheduler starts the Batch File when I am not logged in. If I start it later manually it works fine.

Comment: could you post the code and the error you get? The question is too vague...

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: This error does not belong to the general Code or the HTML. The Problem is, that with the change to headless=new, the windows-size not works anymore.. If I change to headless the Windows sizing works, but the Downloads are not working anymore with the old Headless.

Comment: did you try with `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`?